# Selenium chrome option to enable java to run without asking for permission

Tags: java, selenium, applet, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run selenium script which open a web page where a java applet is loaded. When the java applet is loaded I get a pop "**Java need permission to run on the page**". For firefox, I'm able to skip this by setting "**plugin.state.java" = 2** in FireFox Profile. Can someone let me know the equivalent setting for other browsers like **Chrome, Opera, HTML Unit driver, etc.,**
Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: mind you, that even when that dialog doesn't show, you aren't able to interact inside of the applet.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome: --always-authorize-plugins

[List of Chrome switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)